# Java add .jar files automatically as a a Library

Tags: java, api, github, intellij-idea, jar

I am creating a java project in **IntelliJ** (without maven or grandle). The project uses an external library, whose **.jar** file I’ve put into a **/lib directory**. After that I had to select at the /lib folder **“add as library”** to use it.

Now I want to push the project to **GitHub**, so that some people (who are using IntelliJ as well, but in different versions) can use the project.

Now my question:
**Is there a way, that they do not have to do the step **“add as a library”** themselves?**

My first idea was to push also some parts of the .idea folder to GitHub, but I am not sure which ones to push and if that could actually work (especially with different versions of IntelliJ).

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only IntelliJ for building the project, then yes, you should push the `.iml` files from the `.idea` folder (or where they happen to be), since they contain the dependencies configured in IntelliJ.

Note, that projects with multiple contributors typically use a build tool like Maven or Gradle.

This is a special build requirement, which I would use Gradle for. With Gradle you can look up a given folder, like `/lib` and use all `.jar` files as dependency.
See [Gradle example about exactly what you want](https://riptutorial.com/gradle/example/8349/add-a-local-jar-file-dependency#directory-of-jars).

IntelliJ is handy when you do something simple mostly for learning, but if you want to be a professional one day I highly suggest looking into Gradle. It has a learning curve for sure, but you can achieve such simple tasks like this in your question relatively simply. And as you seem to know, pushing `.idea` to the repository is really not the nicest thing one can do :)

---

Just a small additional note: Gradle solves the "different version" problem by including a "Gradle wrapper" inside the repository, so everyone cloning the repository will have the same copy of Gradle as well, so the same build process is guaranteed for all contributors.

Also, when I started programming I downloaded the dependencies and used them as jars. But if you learn at least Maven, and your dependency is uploaded to a repository like Maven Central, you can just paste a line of code into your `pom.xml` (Maven) or `build.gradle` (Gradle) and you are good to go :)